# Simple parsing JSON data into TypeScript object using React-Query and Axios

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, axios, react-query

Here is my incoming JSON data from server:

```json
{"id" : 1, "text_data": "example data"}
```

Now I am trying to parse this JSON data into TS object like this:

```js
export interface IncomingData {
  id: number;
  text_data: string;
}

function App() {

  // it can be rewritten like 'await axios.get<IncomingData>('http://localhost:3000/api')' and deleted useQuery's turbofish syntax. Nothing changes.
 
  let json_object = useQuery<IncomingData>("data_ex_key", async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api');
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  });

  if (json_object.data !== undefined) {
    console.log(json_object.data.text_data);
  }
}
```

I get `undefined` text in console. Thing is I've already debugged this code with react-query debugger and shows that `json_object` query has successfully fetched data. I can reach this data but cannot reach its properties like `text_data`.

Comment: It can't be awaited and as i said i can have json data but couldn't successfully parse that into object. I can not reach its properties but i can reach json data as whole.

Comment: You may have destructed `data` one too many times; I see you return `response.data` and then access `json_object.data`. Unless the shape of `response` is { data: data: { text_data: string } }` it will return undefined. If `json_object` is of type `IncomingData` you will just want to log `json_object.text_data`

Comment: '.data' property is must have react-query property. i can not reach any fetched data without it. Since i've tried as you said and got 'it is not valid property for this query' error.

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution.

It needs to be array instead of single object.